# Is there any way to have to app next to with ng-admin?

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui, ng-admin

I've like running application on this 
https://github.com/swiip/generator-gulp-angular#readme

Is there any way to implement ng-admin next to my running application?
Because if I have mine `ui-view` in my index.html, ng-admin just overrides everything and throws only errors.

Answer (score 0):

This has already been asked numerous times (see https://github.com/marmelab/ng-admin/issues/335), it's currently not possible. A patch is in the works (https://github.com/marmelab/ng-admin/pull/759), but it breaks BC, so it won't be merged right away.